# How to dynamic CMS pages react JS?

Tags: reactjs

We are using API to fetch CMS page title and other details through the API. We created menu navigation like Home, About, We are. How to load dynamic page content and how create render ?

[Json Data](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=34149d135e3e9d8e3eddc225aec18b67)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
       super(props);

        this.state = { data: [] };

   }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('http://****.com/***/api/products/navigation_menu?app_id=27D8B4AD-170A-4B8E-9852-E48EC5EB42C8')
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({data: res.data.result_set});

      });
  }
  _createMenuItems(){
    return this.state.data.map((loaddata, index)=>
        <li key={index}><Link to={loaddata.pro_cate_slug} >{loaddata.menu_custom_title}</Link></li>
    );
}
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>

               {this._createMenuItems()}
            </ul>

           {this.props.children}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example that should help you get started. I'm essentially using the `App` component to do the rendering for all the routes. A better way would possibly be to create the routes for the pages dynamically and then use specific components for specific pages.

```js
const { Router, Route, Link } = ReactRouter;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { data: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://cdn.rawgit.com/fabe/6929b34fd6f30a13e85ddea480c7053d/raw/5fd6fbe535713c52fd2166e6d0f2d0de01381ff3/gistfile1.json"
      )
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ data: res.data.result_set });
      });
  }
  _getSlug(slug) {
    return slug.split('?')[0];
  }
  _createMenuItems() {
    return this.state.data.map((loaddata, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <Link to={this._getSlug(loaddata.cmspage_slug)}>
        {loaddata.cmspage_title}
      </Link>
      </li>
    ));
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { splat } = this.props.params;
    let description = "";
    // I'm setting the `description` to the corresponding one from the `data` state. `params.splat` is the slug from React Router.
    data.map(page => {
      let pageSlug = this._getSlug(page.cmspage_slug);
      if (pageSlug == splat) {
        description = page.cmspage_meta_description;
      }
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this._createMenuItems()}
        </ul>
        <div>{description}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Use `App` for every route. Probably not the best way to solve this, but it gives you an idea.
ReactDOM.render(
  (
    <Router>
      <Route path="*" component={App} />
    </Router>
  ),
  document.getElementById("View")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-router@2.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.15.3/axios.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="View"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,  it's working. but passing some query string values. how to remove this values.

Comment: Ex. 1.http://localhost:8080/#/we-are?_k=w5ixlf

Comment: It's working. Thanks :)